# Python adds value to Dict and iteratively adds it according to an irregular ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

The problem is this. First of all, I have a file that saves the C language enumeration type. After I post-processed and removes the comment and the useless information, it becomes a format file like this (of course, there is no = The constant string of the symbol is also the result of the processing)

```
SC_ERROR_NETWORK = 00
SC_ERROR_TCP = 01
SC_ERROR_UDP= 02

CLIENT_ERROR_NETWORK = 1000
CLIENT_ERROR_TCP
CLIENT_ERROR_UDP

SERVER_ERROR_NETWORK = 6001
SERVER_ERROR_TCP = 6002
SERVER_ERROR_UDP

TEST_ERROR_TCP = 100001
TEST_ERROR_UDP
```

I want to use python to convert the data into a json or dict type file, there is a key value, and then, for example, next time I add a new string of type SC_ERROR_UDP_TEST in this file below, then he is based on SC_ERROR_UDP = 02, this value, then do the loop, then add the value of SC_ERROR_UDP_TEST to 03, SC_ERROR_UDP_TEST2 to 04, and so on. When the line CLIENT_ERROR_NETWORK = 1000 is encountered, the value of CLIENT_ERROR_NETWORK, which is 1000 as the cyclic base, is added to CLIENT_ERROR_TCP. The value is 1001, CLIENT_ERROR_UDP is 1002, and the same reason is encountered when the following types are encountered (in short, the last last value is used as the base to loop, because it is possible that I will add a new string after the same type name, but I don't want to Every time I manually go to the designated dictionary, I have this requirement.) How can this Python handle and write code? I haven’t succeeded in writing for a long time.

After processing is completed, like this

```
{
   'SC_ERROR_NETWORK':'00'
   'SC_ERROR_TCP':'01'
   'SC_ERROR_UDP':'02'

   'CLIENT_ERROR_NETWORK':'1000'
   'CLIENT_ERROR_TCP':'1001'
   'CLIENT_ERROR_UDP':'1002 '

   'SERVER_ERROR_NETWORK':'6001'
   'SERVER_ERROR_TCP':'6002'
   'SERVER_ERROR_UDP':'6003'

   'TEST_ERROR_TCP':'100001'
   'TEST_ERROR_UDP':'100002'

}
```

Comment: This is a very poorly worded question.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution

```
d = {}
with open(in) as o:
    for line in o:
        tokens = line.strip().split(" = ")
        if len(tokens) > 1:
            d[tokens[0]] = tokens[1]
        else:
            d[tokens[0]] = "NaN"

with open(out) as o:
    o.write(str(d))
```

Comment: Thanks,But it does not solve the problem of automatically adding values